# Using variable interpolation in Gunicorn inside DockerFile

Tags: flask, dockerfile, gunicorn

Looking for a way to pass `PORT` environment variable to `gunicorn` command inside `DockerFile`

current setup

.env

```
PORT=8080
```

DockerFile

```
EXPOSE ${PORT}

CMD ["gunicorn"  , "--timeout" , "120" ,"-b", "0.0.0.0:8080", "wsgi:app"]
```

First attempt

```
CMD ["gunicorn"  , "--timeout" , "120" ,"-b", "0.0.0.0:${PORT}", "wsgi:app"]
```

**Failed**

Second attempt

```
CMD ["gunicorn"  , "--timeout" , "120" ,"-b", "0.0.0.0:{PORT}", "wsgi:app"]
```

**Failed**

What is the correct way to pass PORT to `gunicorn`?

### Update:

I can run the command in `bash` successfully

```
#!/bin/bash
PORT=8879
SERVER_PORT=0.0.0.0:${PORT}
echo ${SERVER_PORT}
gunicorn --bind ${SERVER_PORT} wsgi:app
```

Answer (score -2):

Using Docker's [`ENV`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) directive works for me:

```
ENV PORT 8080

CMD ["gunicorn", "--timeout", "120", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:${PORT}", "wsgi:app"]
```

When I change the `PORT` container environment variable to something other than the specified default of 8080, gunicorn binds to that new port as you'd expect.